# Printing error - forever occuring

Tags: release-loki, printer

I have an Epson WP-4535 printer and every time I try to print, it comes with a notification saying "Printer error" (this notification comes again every five seconds) and no matter how hard I try, I install, uninstall, reinstall the drivers but it just doesn't print. Please can someone explain to me the answer as this **REALLY** annoys me as I need to print lots of things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am a noob but I have managed to print in eOS. I installed the application Synaptic Package Manager, then I looked online for the driver that my printer required, then I found them through the Synaptic Package Manager search and installed them (cups etc.)
You can search within Synaptic Package Manager for the name of your printer and it may come up. It could be the following (printer-driver-escpr)

Answer (score -1):

Does this printer driver work?

Please check.

You can use http://localhost:631 to add the printer. Please see `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` to identify the default port. Look for `Listen` keyword.